# $L_q[0,1]~~$ is a closed proper subspace of $~~L_p[0,1]$

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

Let us consider the Banach spaces $~~(L_p[0,1],\|.\|_p)~~$ and $~~(L_q[0,1],\|.\|_q)~~$ with $~~1 \le p<q\le \infty.~~$  We know that $~~L_q[0,1]~~$ is a proper subspace of $~~L_p[0,1].~$ The norms are defined as
$$\|f\|_p=\left(\int_0^1|f(t)|^pdt\right)^{1/p}~~~\text{ and }~~~\|f\|_q=\left(\int_0^1|f(t)|^qdt\right)^{1/q}.$$
Now, I want to know that, is $~~L_q[0,1]~~$ is a closed proper subspace of $~~L_p[0,1]?~$ I want to find a sequence $~~f_n~~$ in $~~L_q[0,1]~~$ such that $~~\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n \notin L_q[0,1].~~$ Can you please give some time to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, $L_q[0,1]$ contains the linear combinations of indicator functions, hence the closure of $L_q[0,1]$ in $L_p[0,1]$ for the $\lVert \cdot\rVert_p$ norm contains the closure of he linear combinations of indicator functions in $L_p[0,1]$ for the $\lVert \cdot\rVert_p$ norm, which is $L_p[0,1]$.

In other words, $L_q[0,1]$ is a dense subspace of $L_p[0,1]$ for the $\lVert \cdot\rVert_p$ norm.